# PHP const, constant expressions are allowed in const php 7.1?

Tags: php, constants

The following is valid.

```
const BIT_c5 = 1 << 5;
```

The following is not valid.

```
$data_x =10;
$data_y = 20;

const DATA_Y = $data_x + $data_y;
```

Can somebody explain why?

Comment: I think `const` expressions have to be literal expressions

Comment: You can do const `const DATA_X = 10; const DATA_Y = 20; const DATA_Z = self::DATA_X + self::DATA_Y;` (within a class, no need for `self::` outside)

Answer (score 1):

It is there in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php), that while defining a Constant, it must be based on **Constant** expression, not variables etc

> The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a
>   variable, a property, or a function call.

So, you can define a constant and assign immutable value to it based on literals and expressions involving literals. But you cannot use variables (and/or expressions involving variables) to assign the value to constant.